# Specific text with include() and replace() with .map() ES6

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a logic that i could use with .map() to return the desired value. 
Below are 2 variables im using

```
    let _replaceAttr = ['SUM', 'ARRG', 'AGG', 'ATTR', "AVG(pop)"]
    let tempData = ['AVG', 'bob', 'sop']
```

The logic i came with out is returning all as true, if tempData index 0 is set as AVG(pop) , this will return as false.

```
    result = tempData.map(el => !_replaceAttr.includes(el))
    console.log(result);

    // This logic will not apply the updated array element as it will return all as true 
    let es6 = tempData.map(w => !_replaceAttr.includes(w) != true ? w.replace(w, '...') : w)
```

If i were to specifically test this with traditional scripting such as

```
console.log('AVG(pop)'.includes('AVG') 
// This will return as false  which is correct   
// or

//******* Traditional Script ******** 
    for (let i = 0; i < tempData.length; i++) {
        let output = tempData[i]
        for (let a = 0; a < _replaceAttr.length; a++) {
            if (output.includes(_replaceAttr[a])) {
                tempData[i] = tempData[i].replace(_replaceAttr[a], '').replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
            }
        }

    }
    console.log(tempData)
```

The traditional script i have will return the desired output ,i was wondering . Will it be achievable to go with .map() approach on above example.

Comment: Your "traditional script" modifies, parts of an array, in-place. That's nothing `.map()` is meant to do.

Comment: _"The logic i came with out is returning all as true, if tempData index 0 is set as AVG(pop) , this will return as false."_ - Can you please translate that _"logic"_ into an actual [mcve] with input data and the expected output as text.

Comment: .map() expects a function that receives an array element and returns a new value based on that. You can use that to create a modified copy of an array, yes.

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://jsfiddle.net/18x4uva7/